# Returning to different referring pages from an edit page

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC (and not WebFlow).  I have a page setup for editing a particular entity.  This page may be called from many others.  I'm looking for a best-practice as to how to return to the "referring" page after the edit page is POSTed.  That is, what is the best way to determine which page called the edit page and return to that page.

I have my own ideas, but I'm sure many of you have dealt with this before and probably have better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are posting to your edit page, then you can add a value to the posted data that identifys the source page. This technique will allow you to determine the correct view to which to return.

I would do this instead of redirecting to the referring page because it allows you to do any setup required by the source page before you send the user back to the source page.

Comment: We refer to this as a "callback" URL and sometimes we have a Success callback and a Failure callback, if we want to return to different pages based on the result of the Edit.

Comment: Yeah, this is along the lines of what I was thinking.  I pass a parameter into the edit page that identifies the calling page, which I then pick up in the posted data from the edit page and use to return back to the calling page.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the path in `Referer` header field, then you can do a return like this:-

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ... () {
    ...
    return "redirect:"+ request.getHeader("Referer");
}
```

I have seen this approach a few times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to rely on the Referer header. I should have mentioned that in my question.